# How to implement the Metadata 'Uses' tag using typescript

Tags: typescript, solana, metaplex

When we try to mint a new NFT using the createMetadata instruction including the `Uses` tag with `UseMethod: burning`, the method is failing with the following message:

> Uses doesn’t have schema schema.uses.uses.

Any ideas/tips about how to deploy `Uses` with ts or solve the issue on the mpl-token-metadata?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Uses` feature while creating the Metadata Account. I have tried and tested it out and here is how you can structure it out.Make sure to import their types So that there is no type Error in the code.

```
import {
  UseMethod,
  Uses,
  DataV2,
  } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";

 const data: DataV2 = {
  name: "Metaplex",
  symbol: "PAT",
  uri: "https://metadata.degods.com/g/4924.json",
  sellerFeeBasisPoints: 500,
  creators: [
    {
      address: wallet.publicKey,
      verified: true,
      share: 100,
    },
  ],
  collection: null,
  uses: {
    useMethod: UseMethod.Burn,
    remaining: new anchor.BN(5),
    total: new anchor.BN(5),
  },
};
```

Comment: You can get the full code example [here](https://github.com/0xPratik/js-mint-nft/tree/uses)